# My react + express app keeps on telling me my map function is undefined

Tags: reactjs, express

I am creating a react app linked with express that stores web projects in an array and then displays the array on the webpage in a table. I have followed the steps of a tutorial but my app keeps on telling me that it cannot read my "undefined" map function and I dont understand why. It was working and I had to get up to go somewhere and saved and closed my VS code and when i reloaded everything it stopped working

```
APP.JS
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { TableData } from './components/TableData'



function App() {

  const [content, setContent] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then((response) => response.json()
    ).then((response) => {setContent(response)}
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {<TableData projectData={content.webProjects}/>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App


server.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  let webProjects = [

    {
      ID: 1,
      TITLE: "React Game",
      DESCRIPTION: "Tic tac toe game created using Create React App",
      URL: "http://someURL/myapp/game/",
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      TITLE: "Online Store",
      DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Javascript.",
      URL: "http://someURL2/shop/index",
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      TITLE: "Online Store",
      DESCRIPTION: "Online store created with HTML, CSS and Angular.",
      URL: "http://someURL3/shop2/index",
    }
] 
    res.json({ webProjects });
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 5000")
})

TableData.js

import React from 'react'

export const TableData = ({ projectData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="tableheading">
        <strong>My Projects</strong>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>URL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {projectData.map((projectData) => (
                <tr key={projectData.ID}>
                    <td>{projectData.ID}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.TITLE}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.DESCRIPTION}</td>
                    <td>{projectData.URL}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Your projectData may not be ready when you fetch as it is an async function, while TableData is being rendered.  You can put a guard to prevent it from mapping until it is ready may be?

projectData && projectData.map(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is your `content` state variable initially has `[{}]` value (weird choice but that's not the point, so moving on...), and thus `content.webProjects` evaluates to `undefined`.

And in your `TableData` component, you're trying to call `.map()` of this undefined value, so until the API returns, you'll keep getting this error.

The solution is either check the validity of `projectData` before calling `.map()`:

```
projectData?.map(...)
```

Or, set the initial state so that `webProjects` exists as an empty array:

```
const [content, setContent] = useState({ webProjects: [] });
```